# Check if a string value of a column in a Pandas DataFrame starts with the value of another column

Tags: python, pandas, startswith

I am trying to concatenate two string columns `col1` and `col2` in a Pandas DataFrame. But I do not want to concatenate them if `col2`’s value already begins with the value of `col1`. In this case I want to use `col2` without concatenation. This would be the expected behavior:

| col1 | col2 | result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | ABC | ABC |
| ABC | XYC | ABCXYZ |
| ABC | abc123 | abc123 |

I tried this code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': ['ABC', 'ABC', 'AbC'],
    'col2': ['ABC', 'XYZ', 'abc123'],
})


df['result'] = df['col2'].where(df['col2'].str.lower().str.startswith(df['col1'].str.lower()), df['col1'] + df['col2'])

df
```

But that results in:

| col1 | col2 | result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | ABC | ABCABC |
| ABC | XYC | ABCXYZ |
| ABC | abc123 | AbCabc123 |

For testing purposes I used a string literal as parameter for startswith and received the expected results:

```
df['result'] = df['col2'].where(df['col2'].str.lower().str.startswith('abc'), df['col1'] + df['col2'])
```

I found out that the result of the `startswith` function always returns `NaN`:

```
df['result'] = df['col2'].str.lower().str.startswith(df['col1'].str.lower())
```

| col1 | col2 | result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | ABC | NaN |
| ABC | XYC | NaN |
| ABC | abc123 | NaN |

If I replace the `startswith` parameter with a string literal I receive booleans as expected:

```
df['result'] = df['col2'].str.lower().str.startswith('abc')
```

| col1 | col2 | result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | ABC | True |
| ABC | XYC | False |
| ABC | abc123 | True |

I understand that it seems to be a problem to use a series as a parameter in the `startswith` function. But I do not get it to work.

I am very new to Python and Pandas, I intensively used search engines and stackoverflow's search function before I created my first post. What do I have to change in my code to accomplish the desired behavior? Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `startswith` doesn't take a series, it takes a literal string.

Comment: Thanks, for you quick comment, @ifly6. I already found out that `startswith` works with a string literal while it has problems with a series. And it works with string variables as well. Do you also have a hint for me how I can accomplish my desired behavior? That would really help. Thanks :-)

Comment: This may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64331712/pandas-startswith-operation-between-two-columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64332351/18090994

Write your own `startswith` function and vectorize it with [numpy.vectorize](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html). In this way, you can compare the strings in `col1` and `col2` row by row.

```py
from numpy import vectorize

def startswith(str1, str2):
  """Check if str1 starts with str2 (case insensitive)"""
  return str1.lower().startswith(str2.lower())

startswith = vectorize(startswith)
df['result'] = df['col2'].where(startswith(df['col2'], df['col1']), df['col1'] + df['col2'])
```

Comment: It is not recommended to say thank you in a comment. I will do it anyway and delete this comment in a few days: This answer is fantastic and helped me a lot. I will have to learn about the vectorize function. I would have never ever figured out how to solve my problem. Thanks again @Flursch!